# How to keep (absolute) footer at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to keep my footer at the bottom of the page while keeping there position absolute , the have the following page structure :

```
<div id="head"> </div> //want to keep its size auto and always on the top (position absolute) 
<div id="body"> </div> //the children of #body have position absolute (keep size auto)
<div id="foot"> </div> //want to keep this at the bottom (just below body , if body size 
                         changes then footer will also change (position absolute)
```

How can i do this?

**Edit**

I think i was not clear to my question, sorry for that but my actual problem is that in #main ( height : auto ) the contents are absolute so those contents are not included in the height of main ( i am just guessing this ) thats why the height of main was 0 because of this the footer comes up. This is my actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bottom:0`:

```
#foot {
  position:absolute; /* your requirement, you can also use fixed though */
  bottom:0;
  /* your other possible styles */
}
```

Just keep in mind that for `bottom` to work, you got to specify the `position` as you said :)

If you use `position:fixed`, the footer will still be available on bottom of the page when you ***scroll*** but it is up to your requirements.

Comment: Thnaks for answer, but please check my Edit

Comment: @KingKong: That's a different problem, you need to post a new question describing your problem accurately there (important). This thread answers your asked question.

Comment: I posted my problem please have a look at it

Comment: @KingKong: Thanks now more people will be able to look at your question including me :)

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly you need `position:fixed` and not absolute..

```
#head {
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#foot{
    position:fixed;
    height:40px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#body{
    padding-top:30px; /* the same as the #head height*/
    padding-bottom:40px; /* the same as the #foot height*/
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMTR/

Comment: This will work only if you now the height of the #foot and #head.

Comment: that is true.. (*you could adjust the #body paddings with js, though, once the page is loaded..*)